# Why can't I return it to the str() built-in function after the reversed() function?

Tags: python

```py
a = '123asdad'


str(reversed(a))
>> '<reversed object at 0x00000206C9F80250>'


list(reversed(a))
>> ['d', 'a', 'd', 's', 'a', '3', '2', '1']
```

I already know that the best way is a[::-1].

But I want to know why I can't convert the reversed object into a str() function. list() or tuple() is possible, but why not str()?

All three are iterable objects and Seqence type objects, is there anything I don't know?

Comment: `str` ask for the string representation of the object, that is defined to be the class name and an address. whereas `list` iterates the object

Comment: You *did* convert the `reversed` object into a `str`. The `str` class returns a `str` object from any given object. What did you **expect** `str(reversed(a))` to return?

Comment: `str` calls `__str__` on the object passed if present else `__repr__` unlike like `tuple` and `list`, which convert a sequence to the corresponding type.

Comment: @Ch3steR well, `str` converts an object into a `str`...

Comment: `''.join(reversed(a))` is one other way of doing it

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga True, but the returned string is determined by the `__str__` or `__repr__` function is what I meant to say. I worded it very poorly now that I reread it. English is not my first language.

Comment: An object which does not have a defined string output (either in its `__repr__` or `__str__` methods), will be outputted generically like `'<reversed object at 0x00000206C9F80250>'`. A `reversed` object is iterable, meaning it can be converted into a `list` or `tuple`, but it has no inherent `str` representation because it's not just a class meant for holding strings. There could be anything in the reversed list. So, trying to convert to a string would be fraught with pitfalls because there's no guarantee that each item in the reversed list is a string.

Comment: The result you get from `str(reversed(a))` is similar what you get from calling `str` on a generic iterable.  For example `str(zip(['abc'], ['def']))` gives `<zip object at blahblah>`.  It's not the case that `str(iterable)` generically gets items from the iterable and concatenates them into a string.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: "`str` converts an object into a `str`" — no it doesn't.  It returns `object.__str__()` and that's it.

Comment: @KlasŠ. **that is converting an object into a `str`**. In what sense do you think that is different than *any other constructors*? Like `list`, `tuple`, `int`, `float`, etc etc. Also, that isn't *all* it does. That is *one hook* that is used by the `str` constructor.

Comment: *"In what sense do you think that is different than any other constructors?"* — I wouldn't say constructors convert objects.

Comment: *"That is one hook that is used by the str constructor"* — agreed.  But I don't think anybody would call `'<reversed object at 0x00000206C9F80250>'` a `reversed` object converted to string.

Comment: generators have also their `__str__` and `__repr__` methods so when you print them you are calling the method of the container object not of its content

Answer (score 5):

> All three are iterable objects and Seqence type objects, is there anything I don't know?

You're correct, they're all iterable objects, but they each have a different implementation of `__str__`.

If you expect `str(reversed(a))` to return `"['d', 'a', 'd', 's', 'a', '3', '2', '1']"`, then what you're essential asking is for the `reversed` class to have the same behaviour of `__str__` as `list`.

This would actually be quite confusing, because it would blur the distinction between objects of `reversed` and `list`. They're intentionally different. A `reversed` object wraps an underlying collection and behaves *as if* it had reversed all the elements in memory, without actually wasting CPU/memory to reverse all the elements in memory.

If you do want the `list` behaviour of `__str__`, then use *it*:

```py
str(list(reversed(a)))
```

Of course, you should notice that this ends up doing all the reversing for real, copying the elements into a new list in the reversed order. If that's undesirable, then you'll have to implement your own formatting code to iterate a `reversed` object (or any iterable, really), quoting its elements, joining them with `,`  and surrounding them with `[ ]`.

Answer (score 1):

`str` calls the `__str__` function on the object (which is what is called when the object is `print`ed, so there is no difference between the output of `str(reversed(a))` and `reversed(a)` in a REPL).

---

The `__str__` function is automatically generated if neither that nor the `__repr__` function is provided.

You can see this here:

```py
class Foo:
    pass

my_obj = Foo()
print(my_obj)
```

Output: `<__main__.Foo object at 0x7ffa890ab5e0>`

The `reversed` class doesn't provide a `__str__` function, so `str(reversed(a))` will return the automatically generated value

---

Use `''.join(reversed(a))` to get the desired output:

```py
>>> a = '123asdad'
>>> ''.join(reversed(a))
'dadsa321'
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question _"why I can't convert the reversed object into a str() function"_. Also, _"There is no difference between `str(reversed(a))` and `reversed(a)`"_ is only correct if you're running it in a REPL which prints the value of expressions, as evidenced by `rev = reversed(a); assert str(rev) == rev`.

Comment: Yeah, but there's no difference between `print(str(reversed(a)))` and `print(reversed(a))`, and also from the code OP has given it looks like it is being run in a REPL

Comment: There's also no difference between `print(1)` and `print('1')`, but that doesn't make them the same.

Comment: I was talking about the output in a REPL ("there is no difference between the output of `str(reversed(a))` and `reversed(a)` in a REPL")